# boost 1.48 filesystem3 symbol link error ploblem

Tags: boost-filesystem

My project setting : 
/I"..\ANTLR_LIB" /I"..\eNITL" /I"......\boost" /ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /MP /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /D "BOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H" /GF- /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MTd /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yu"StdAfx.h" /Fp"Debug\PIDL_UnProtect.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gz /wd"4996" /analyze- /errorReport:queue

link boost library :

boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_48.lib
boost\bin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-sgd-1_48.lib

but this error occured. what is problem??

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall boost::filesystem3::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &,class std::codecvt const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem3@boost@@YGXPBD0AAV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@_WDH@5@@Z) referenced in function "void __stdcall boost::filesystem3::path_traits::dispatch,class std::allocator > >(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &,class std::codecvt const &)" (??$dispatch@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@path_traits@filesystem3@boost@@YGXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@4@ABV?$codecvt@_WDH@4@@Z)
3>PIDL.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall boost::filesystem3::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &,class std::codecvt const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem3@boost@@YGXPBD0AAV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@_WDH@5@@Z)
3>Backend.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall boost::filesystem3::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &,class std::codecvt const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem3@boost@@YGXPB_W0AAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@_WDH@5@@Z) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const __thiscall boost::filesystem3::path::string(class std::codecvt const &)const " (?string@path@filesystem3@boost@@QBE?BV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@_WDH@5@@Z)
3>PIDL.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall boost::filesystem3::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &,class std::codecvt const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem3@boost@@YGXPB_W0AAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@_WDH@5@@Z)
3>Backend.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::codecvt const * & __stdcall boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet(void)" (?wchar_t_codecvt_facet@path@filesystem3@boost@@CGAAPBV?$codecvt@_WDH@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class std::codecvt const & __stdcall boost::filesystem3::path::codecvt(void)" (?codecvt@path@filesystem3@boost@@SGABV?$codecvt@_WDH@std@@XZ)
3>PIDL.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::codecvt const * & __stdcall boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet(void)" (?wchar_t_codecvt_facet@path@filesystem3@boost@@CGAAPBV?$codecvt@_WDH@std@@XZ)
3>PIDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::filesystem3::file_status __stdcall boost::filesystem3::detail::status(class boost::filesystem3::path const &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?status@detail@filesystem3@boost@@YG?AVfile_status@23@ABVpath@23@PAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) referenced in function "bool __stdcall boost::filesystem3::exists(class boost::filesystem3::path const &)" (?exists@filesystem3@boost@@YG_NABVpath@12@@Z)
3>PIDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __stdcall boost::filesystem3::detail::create_directory(class boost::filesystem3::path const &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?create_directory@detail@filesystem3@boost@@YG_NABVpath@23@PAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) referenced in function "bool __stdcall boost::filesystem3::create_directory(class boost::filesystem3::path const &)" (?create_directory@filesystem3@boost@@YG_NABVpath@12@@Z)
3>PIDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::filesystem3::path __stdcall boost::filesystem3::detail::initial_path(class boost::system::error_code *)" (?initial_path@detail@filesystem3@boost@@YG?AVpath@23@PAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) referenced in function "class boost::filesystem3::path __stdcall boost::filesystem3::initial_path(void)" (?initial_path@filesystem3@boost@@YG?AVpath@12@XZ)
3>PIDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __stdcall boost::filesystem3::detail::remove(class boost::filesystem3::path const &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?remove@detail@filesystem3@boost@@YG_NABVpath@23@PAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) referenced in function "bool __stdcall boost::filesystem3::remove(class boost::filesystem3::path const &)" (?remove@filesystem3@boost@@YG_NABVpath@12@@Z)
3>PIDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall boost::filesystem3::detail::directory_iterator_construct(class boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator &,class boost::filesystem3::path const &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?directory_iterator_construct@detail@filesystem3@boost@@YGXAAVdirectory_iterator@23@ABVpath@23@PAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(class boost::filesystem3::path const &)" (??0directory_iterator@filesystem3@boost@@QAE@ABVpath@12@@Z)
3>PIDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall boost::filesystem3::detail::directory_iterator_increment(class boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?directory_iterator_increment@detail@filesystem3@boost@@YGXAAVdirectory_iterator@23@PAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator::increment(void)" (?increment@directory_iterator@filesystem3@boost@@AAEXXZ)
3>PIDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_code __stdcall boost::filesystem3::detail::dir_itr_close(void * &)" (?dir_itr_close@detail@filesystem3@boost@@YG?AVerror_code@system@3@AAPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::filesystem3::detail::dir_itr_imp::~dir_itr_imp(void)" (??1dir_itr_imp@detail@filesystem3@boost@@QAE@XZ)
3>stdafx.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __stdcall boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YGABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'posix_category''(void)" (??__Eposix_category@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
3>stdafx.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __stdcall boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YGABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'native_ecat''(void)" (??__Enative_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)

Comment: I solved this ploblem. My project's calling convention is __stdcall. so, changed __cdecl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to link Boost 1.52 thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674374/trying-to-link-boost-1-52-thread)